# Motion issues with ParallelTransition´s Event Handler in JavaFx 8

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am working on a College project in javafx: a Game like Space Invaders.I was trying to make The animation of each ovni with a **ParallelTransition**, creating a **TimeLine** animation and adding it to the ParallelTransition for each of them, managing a EventHandler for each of them in order to move the ovni in X position and moving in Y when it comes to the left bound of the window.The issue is that when i am playing the animation, only the first row moves correctly in x position, but the other rows don´t. In other words, when the other rows move some distance on x position, they don´t finish their motion on the rigth bound,but they move in Y position instead.Resulting of something like that:

This is the method to buildOvni:

```
public Shape buildOvni(){
    Arc arcCuerpo=new Arc(Constantes.POS_CUERPO_OVNI_X,Constantes.POS_CUERPO_OVNI_Y,Constantes.ANCHO_CUERPO_OVNI,Constantes.ALTO_CUERPO_OVNI,0,180);
    Arc arcL=new Arc(Constantes.POS_ARC_IZQ_X,Constantes.POS_ARC_IZQ_Y,Constantes.ANCHO_ARC_IZQ,Constantes.ALTO_ARC_IZQ,180,180);
    Arc arcCentro=new Arc(Constantes.POS_ARC_CTR_X,Constantes.POS_ARC_CTR_Y,Constantes.ANCHO_ARC_CTR,Constantes.ALTO_ARC_CTR,180,180);
    Arc arcD=new Arc(Constantes.POS_ARC_DER_X,Constantes.POS_ARC_DER_Y,Constantes.ANCHO_ARC_DER,Constantes.ALTO_ARC_DER,180,180);
    Shape union1=Shape.union(arcCuerpo, arcL);
    Shape union2=Shape.union(union1, arcCentro);
    Shape union3=Shape.union(union2, arcD);

    return union3;
}
```

Secondly, I have declared two matrix for ovnis: one for Panes that will contain each ovni´s shape; and other that will contains the ovni objects.

```
  public Juego(){
    lab=new Label();
    transicionEnY=new ParallelTransition();
    dir=new File(Constantes.GAME_BACKGROUND);
    Pane navePane=new Pane();
    paneOvnis=new Pane[3][6]; //the panes for each ovni´s shape
    nave=new Nave(navePane);
    gameContainer=new Pane();
    gameContainer.getChildren().addAll(navePane);
    background=new Image(dir.toURI().toString());
    pane=new BorderPane();
    pane.setCenter(gameContainer);
    pane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(background,null,null,null,new BackgroundSize(Constantes.MAXIMUM_WIDHT,Constantes.MAXIMUM_HEIGTH,false,false,false,true))));
    //playMusic();
    agregarOvnis();
    moverOvnis();
   pane.setBottom(lab);
}
```

The method to populate each matrix:

```
public void agregarOvnis(){
    this.ovnis=new Ovni[paneOvnis.length][paneOvnis[0].length];
    for(int i=0;i<paneOvnis.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<paneOvnis[0].length;j++){    
            Pane paneOvni=new Pane();
            Ovni ovni=new OvniGris(paneOvni);
            ovni.setLocation(Constantes.POS_OVNI_X+Constantes.OVNI_SPACING_X*j,Constantes.POS_OVNI_Y+Constantes.OVNI_SPACING_Y*i);
            this.gameContainer.getChildren().add(paneOvni);
            this.paneOvnis[i][j]=paneOvni;
            this.ovnis[i][j]=ovni;
        }
    }
}
```

The method that make declare the ParallelTransition and make TimeLine animations for each ovni:

```
    public void moverOvnis(){
    ParallelTransition animaciones=new ParallelTransition();
    for(int i=0;i<ovnis.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<ovnis[i].length;j++){
            Timeline animacionOvnis=new Timeline();
            KeyFrame kf=new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(900),new ManejadorMovimientos(i,j));
            animacionOvnis.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
            animacionOvnis.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            animacionOvnis.setAutoReverse(false);
            animaciones.getChildren().add(animacionOvnis);
        }
    }
    animaciones.play();
}
```

Finally, this is the TimeLine EventHandler class to make the ovni motion for each ovni:

```
private class ManejadorMovimientos implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

    int i;
    int j;
    int orientacion=1;

    public ManejadorMovimientos(int i, int j){
        this.i=i;
        this.j=j;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        double distanciaMaxDer=maxDistanceRight();
        double distanciaMaxIzq=maxDistanceLeft();
        lab.setText(""+distanciaMaxDer+","+ovnis[0][5].getXLocation());
        if(orientacion==1)
           if(distanciaMaxDer-30>0){ 
            ovnis[i][j].setLocation(ovnis[i][j].getXLocation()+30,ovnis[i][j].getYLocation());
           }
           else{
            ovnis[i][j].setLocation(ovnis[i][j].getXLocation(),ovnis[i][j].getYLocation()+20);   
            orientacion=-1;                
           }
        else{
           if(distanciaMaxIzq-30>30){ 
           ovnis[i][j].setLocation(ovnis[i][j].getXLocation()-30,ovnis[i][j].getYLocation());
           }
           else{
            ovnis[i][j].setLocation(ovnis[i][j].getXLocation(),ovnis[i][j].getYLocation()+20);
            orientacion=1;
           }
        }

    }

    private double maxDistanceRight(){
        int j=ovnis[0].length-1;
        while(j>=0){
            for(int i=0;i<ovnis.length;i++){
                if(ovnis[i][j]!=null){
                    return 1.25*Constantes.MAXIMUM_WIDHT-ovnis[i][j].getXLocation();
                }
            }
            j--;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private double maxDistanceLeft(){
        int j=0;
        while(j<ovnis[0].length){
            for(int i=0;i<ovnis.length;i++){
                if(ovnis[i][j]!=null){
                    return ovnis[i][j].getXLocation()-30;
                }
            }
            j++;
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

I leave here the Constants,Ovni and Game Class,respectively, for more information (Sorry for some words in spanish,it´s part of the requeriments of my project.)

**Constants Class**

```
    public class Constantes {

//PARAMETROS GENERALES DEL JUEGO
public static final double MENU_HEIGTH= 600;
public static final double MENU_WIDTH=  500;
public static final double MAXIMUM_HEIGTH = 800;
public static final double MAXIMUM_WIDHT= 640;
public static final String MAIN_LOGO="src/backgrounds/logo.png";
public static final String MAIN_BACKGROUND="src/backgrounds/mainbackground2.jpg";
public static final String GAME_BACKGROUND="src/backgrounds/gamebackground2.jpg";
public static final String GAME_BACKGROUND_MUSIC="src/sounds/game.mp3";
public static final String MAIN_BACKGROUND_MUSIC="src/sounds/main.mp3";

//PARAMETROS DE CONSTRUCCION DE LA NAVE
public static final double POS_NAVE_X=MAXIMUM_WIDHT/2;
public static final double POS_NAVE_Y=MAXIMUM_HEIGTH-295;
public static final double ANCHO_REC_A=50;
public static final double ALTO_REC_A=18;
public static final double POS_REC_A_X=(POS_NAVE_X/4)-(ANCHO_REC_A/2);
public static final double POS_REC_A_Y=POS_NAVE_Y-400;
public static final double ANCHO_REC_B=ANCHO_REC_A*0.66667;
public static final double ALTO_REC_B=10;
public static final double POS_REC_B_X=POS_REC_A_X+ANCHO_REC_B/4;
public static final double POS_REC_B_Y=POS_NAVE_Y-405;
public static final double ANCHO_REC_C=ANCHO_REC_B*0.225;
public static final double ALTO_REC_C=10;
public static final double POS_REC_C_X=POS_REC_B_X+ANCHO_REC_B/2;
public static final double POS_REC_C_Y=POS_REC_B_Y;
public static final double ANCHO_REC_D=ANCHO_REC_C*0.45;
public static final double ALTO_REC_D=10;
public static final double POS_REC_D_X=POS_REC_C_X-1;
public static final double POS_REC_D_Y=POS_REC_C_Y-ALTO_REC_C-ALTO_REC_D+ALTO_REC_C/2;


//PARAMETROS DE CONSTRUCCION DEL OVNI
public static final double POS_OVNI_X=70;
public static final double POS_OVNI_Y=40;
public static final double POS_CUERPO_OVNI_X=0;
public static final double POS_CUERPO_OVNI_Y=0;
public static final double ANCHO_CUERPO_OVNI=23;
public static final double ALTO_CUERPO_OVNI=15;
public static final double ANCHO_ARC_IZQ=ANCHO_CUERPO_OVNI*0.22;
public static final double ALTO_ARC_IZQ=ALTO_CUERPO_OVNI*0.55;
public static final double POS_ARC_IZQ_X=POS_CUERPO_OVNI_X - ANCHO_CUERPO_OVNI * 0.80 + ANCHO_ARC_IZQ / 2;
public static final double POS_ARC_IZQ_Y=POS_CUERPO_OVNI_Y;
public static final double ANCHO_ARC_CTR=ANCHO_CUERPO_OVNI*0.35;
public static final double ALTO_ARC_CTR=ALTO_CUERPO_OVNI*0.30;
public static final double POS_ARC_CTR_X=POS_CUERPO_OVNI_X;
public static final double POS_ARC_CTR_Y=POS_CUERPO_OVNI_Y;
public static final double ANCHO_ARC_DER=ANCHO_CUERPO_OVNI*0.22;
public static final double ALTO_ARC_DER=ALTO_CUERPO_OVNI*0.55;
public static final double POS_ARC_DER_X=POS_CUERPO_OVNI_X + ANCHO_CUERPO_OVNI * 0.60 + ANCHO_ARC_DER / 2;
public static final double POS_ARC_DER_Y=POS_CUERPO_OVNI_Y;
public static final double POS_OVNI_WINDOW_X=POS_CUERPO_OVNI_X - ANCHO_CUERPO_OVNI * 0.80;
public static final double POS_OVNI_WINDOW_Y=POS_CUERPO_OVNI_Y - ANCHO_CUERPO_OVNI / 2;
public static final double OVNI_SPACING_X=70;
public static final double OVNI_SPACING_Y=30;

//PARAMETROS DE MOVIMIENTO NAVE
public static final double MOVIMIENTO_NAVE=2;

//PARAMETROS DE MOVIMIENTO OVNI
```

}

**OVNI Class**

```
public abstract class Ovni {
protected Shape ovni;

public Ovni(Pane pane){
    ovni=buildOvni();
    pane.getChildren().add(ovni);
}

public void setLocation(double x,double y){
    ovni.setLayoutX(x);
    ovni.setLayoutY(y);
}

public double getXLocation(){
   return ovni.getLayoutX();
}

public double getYLocation(){
   return ovni.getLayoutY();
}

public Shape getOvni() {
    return ovni;
}

public void setOvni(Shape ovni) {
    this.ovni = ovni;
}

public Shape buildOvni(){
    Arc arcCuerpo=new Arc(Constantes.POS_CUERPO_OVNI_X,Constantes.POS_CUERPO_OVNI_Y,Constantes.ANCHO_CUERPO_OVNI,Constantes.ALTO_CUERPO_OVNI,0,180);
    Arc arcL=new Arc(Constantes.POS_ARC_IZQ_X,Constantes.POS_ARC_IZQ_Y,Constantes.ANCHO_ARC_IZQ,Constantes.ALTO_ARC_IZQ,180,180);
    Arc arcCentro=new Arc(Constantes.POS_ARC_CTR_X,Constantes.POS_ARC_CTR_Y,Constantes.ANCHO_ARC_CTR,Constantes.ALTO_ARC_CTR,180,180);
    Arc arcD=new Arc(Constantes.POS_ARC_DER_X,Constantes.POS_ARC_DER_Y,Constantes.ANCHO_ARC_DER,Constantes.ALTO_ARC_DER,180,180);
    Shape union1=Shape.union(arcCuerpo, arcL);
    Shape union2=Shape.union(union1, arcCentro);
    Shape union3=Shape.union(union2, arcD);

    return union3;
}
```

}

GAME class

```
public class Juego {
private BorderPane pane;
private Pane gameContainer;
private File dir;
private Image background;
private MediaPlayer player;
private Nave nave;
private Pane[][] paneOvnis;
private Ovni[][] ovnis;
private final ParallelTransition transicionEnY;
Label lab;
/**
 *
 */
public Juego(){
    lab=new Label();
    transicionEnY=new ParallelTransition();
    dir=new File(Constantes.GAME_BACKGROUND);
    Pane navePane=new Pane();
    paneOvnis=new Pane[3][6];
    nave=new Nave(navePane);
    gameContainer=new Pane();
    gameContainer.getChildren().addAll(navePane);
    background=new Image(dir.toURI().toString());
    pane=new BorderPane();
    pane.setCenter(gameContainer);
    pane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(background,null,null,null,new BackgroundSize(Constantes.MAXIMUM_WIDHT,Constantes.MAXIMUM_HEIGTH,false,false,false,true))));
    //playMusic();
    agregarOvnis();
    moverOvnis();
   pane.setBottom(lab);
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 */
public BorderPane getRoot(){
    return pane;
}

/**
 *
 */
public void playMusic(){
    File dir=new File(Constantes.GAME_BACKGROUND_MUSIC);
    Media music=new Media(dir.toURI().toString());
    player=new MediaPlayer(music);
    player.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
            player.seek(Duration.ZERO);
        }
    });
    player.play();
}

public void agregarOvnis(){
    this.ovnis=new Ovni[paneOvnis.length][paneOvnis[0].length];
    for(int i=0;i<paneOvnis.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<paneOvnis[0].length;j++){    
            Pane paneOvni=new Pane();
            Ovni ovni=new OvniGris(paneOvni);
            ovni.setLocation(Constantes.POS_OVNI_X+Constantes.OVNI_SPACING_X*j,Constantes.POS_OVNI_Y+Constantes.OVNI_SPACING_Y*i);
            this.gameContainer.getChildren().add(paneOvni);
            this.paneOvnis[i][j]=paneOvni;
            this.ovnis[i][j]=ovni;
        }
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @param e
 */
public void moverNave(Event e){
    ManejadorTeclas manager=new ManejadorTeclas();
    manager.handle((KeyEvent) e);
}

public void moverOvnis(){
    ParallelTransition animaciones=new ParallelTransition();
    for(int i=0;i<ovnis.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<ovnis[i].length;j++){
            Timeline animacionOvnis=new Timeline();
            KeyFrame kf=new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(900),new ManejadorMovimientos(i,j));
            animacionOvnis.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
            animacionOvnis.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            animacionOvnis.setAutoReverse(false);
            animaciones.getChildren().add(animacionOvnis);
        }
    }
    animaciones.play();
}

private class ManejadorTeclas implements EventHandler<KeyEvent>{

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        double movimiento=Constantes.MOVIMIENTO_NAVE;
        if(event.getCode()==KeyCode.RIGHT && nave.getLocationX()+Constantes.MOVIMIENTO_NAVE<Constantes.MAXIMUM_WIDHT )
            nave.setLocationX(nave.getLocationX()+3);
        else if(event.getCode()==KeyCode.LEFT && nave.getLocationX()-Constantes.MOVIMIENTO_NAVE>0 )
            nave.setLocationX(nave.getLocationX()-3);
        else if(event.getCode()==KeyCode.ESCAPE){ 
            pane.getScene().getWindow().hide();
        }
    }
}

private class ManejadorMovimientos implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

    int i;
    int j;
    int orientacion=1;

    public ManejadorMovimientos(int i, int j){
        this.i=i;
        this.j=j;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        double distanciaMaxDer=maxDistanceRight();
        double distanciaMaxIzq=maxDistanceLeft();
        lab.setText(""+distanciaMaxDer+","+ovnis[0][5].getXLocation());
        if(orientacion==1)
           if(distanciaMaxDer-30>0){ 
            ovnis[i][j].setLocation(ovnis[i][j].getXLocation()+30,ovnis[i][j].getYLocation());
           }
           else{
            ovnis[i][j].setLocation(ovnis[i][j].getXLocation(),ovnis[i][j].getYLocation()+20);   
            orientacion=-1;                
           }
        else{
           if(distanciaMaxIzq-30>30){ 
           ovnis[i][j].setLocation(ovnis[i][j].getXLocation()-30,ovnis[i][j].getYLocation());
           }
           else{
            ovnis[i][j].setLocation(ovnis[i][j].getXLocation(),ovnis[i][j].getYLocation()+20);
            orientacion=1;
           }
        }

    }

    private double maxDistanceRight(){
        int j=ovnis[0].length-1;
        while(j>=0){
            for(int i=0;i<ovnis.length;i++){
                if(ovnis[i][j]!=null){
                    return 1.25*Constantes.MAXIMUM_WIDHT-ovnis[i][j].getXLocation();
                }
            }
            j--;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private double maxDistanceLeft(){
        int j=0;
        while(j<ovnis[0].length){
            for(int i=0;i<ovnis.length;i++){
                if(ovnis[i][j]!=null){
                    return ovnis[i][j].getXLocation()-30;
                }
            }
            j++;
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: This is how it results:

http://imgur.com/a/jFObp

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're updating the positions line by line and recalculate the rightmost position every time. In the order you added the `Timeline`s to the `ParallelTransition`, the top right ouvi is updated before the lower ouvis are updated which means those ouvis will consider the rightmost position to be reached one "frame" before the ouvis in the topmost line which causes the issue.

**Additional notes:**

Using a `ParallelTransition` in this case is unnecessary/inefficient, since a single `Timeline` can handle all the `KeyFrame`s. Furthermore even multiple `KeyFrame`s are unnecessary, since the ouvis are all updated at the same time and even some values *should be*  reused.

The following example moves around simpler objects:

```
private Rectangle[][] rects = new Rectangle[3][3];

private void moveDown() {
    for (Rectangle[] column : rects) {
        for (Rectangle r : column) {
            if (r != null) {
                r.setY(r.getY() + 5);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    for (int j = 0; j < rects.length; j++) {
        Rectangle[] column = rects[j];
        for (int i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20, 20);
            rect.setX(j * 25);
            rect.setY(i * 25);
            root.getChildren().add(rect);
            column[i] = rect;
        }
    }
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        boolean movingRight = true;

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            double maxX = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
            double minX = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
            outer:
            for (int i = rects.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                for (Rectangle r : rects[i]) {
                    if (r != null) {
                        maxX = r.getX() + r.getWidth();
                        break outer;
                    }
                }
            }
            outer:
            for (Rectangle[] col : rects) {
                for (Rectangle r : col) {
                    if (r != null) {
                        minX = r.getX();
                        break outer;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (movingRight) {
                if (maxX + 5 > 150) {
                    moveDown();
                    movingRight = false;
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                if (minX - 5 < 0) {
                    moveDown();
                    movingRight = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
            double dx = movingRight ? 5 : -5;
            for (Rectangle[] column : rects) {
                for (Rectangle r : column) {
                    if (r != null) {
                        r.setX(r.getX() + dx);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 150, 600);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me!!!!! This example works fine for my project.